# Which is better performance wise - Divide a table to two or increase the column count - Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, database-design, database-performance

Suppose there is an Oracal table which may have 200 columns and 2000K rows. Suppose I have to add a new column to the table. Since the column count is on the high side (even though the max column count is 1000 i think 200 is high side) I can create a new table with the primary key columns and my new column or I can add the new column to the existing table. Which will be performance wise better. Which will be overall better design. If you can elaborate and lead me for more information it would be better. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This surely depends on what you are doing with the data afterwards.  If you mostly deal with the new column in isolation from other columns, then two tables might be better. If the new column is involved in most queries and updates, one might expect a single table to be better. Probably you should try both and see, though as it's definitely one of those "it depends" questions

Comment: There will be updates, mostly selects. The column would be not that much isolated. Is there a way to determine the performance of these, I mean a way like bench mark? Do oracle support for that?. Thanks.

Comment: I haven't used Oracle in a while and I don't have a copy handy, but most modern SQL DBs have some sort of "explain plan" function that gives you a measurement of how much resources a query will take. Ooh, I just googled "oracle explain plan" and it says there is a "cost" column in the output. You can create a database with 3 tables -- the one consolidated table and also the two separate tables -- and type in some queries trying it both ways and see what cost each gets. For a real test, write a program that runs the queries a few thousand times and see what the actual run time of each is.

Comment: BTW "explain plan" is a very underused feature of a DBMS. You should use it ALL THE TIME on complex queries, get a feel for what a reasonable cost for a query is, and then if you see the cost on a query is high, figure out what you can do to bring it down. I've seen many, many queries that are absurdly slow and are easily fixed by adding an index or tinkering with the joins, subqueries, etc.

Comment: Thanks Jay,  I will try to do some digging on "explain plan" and try look at my query from it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, "It depends".

If most of the time you need to use only a small subset of the columns, like if there are 200 columns but 90% of the time you use just columns 1, 3, and 24, and the other columns are used relatively rarely, then breaking it into 2 tables, with one table having the most frequently used columns, and the other table having the less frequently used columns, would make the reads of the frequently used columns faster, because there is less data to read -- you don't have to skip over all the irrelevant data.

But if most of the time you use all 200 columns, or you use the columns in many different combinations, like one query uses columns 1, 2, and 7; another uses 1, 24, and 32; another uses 2, 7, and 32; etc. then breaking into two tables will make it slower. If you regularly have to read two tables to get all the data, that means two separate index look ups (or worse, two separate sequential searches). Finding a record in a table is a relatively expensive operation, much more expensive than skipping over fields that you don't need.

But all that said: I would be very cautious about breaking something that is logically one table into two for performance reasons. Never, ever do this because you think that it might be a problem. Only do it when experimentation or calculation shows that it really is a problem, that is, when you discover that, in practice, performance is inadequate or the burden on the server is too large. You might conclude that this sort of denormalization for performance is necessary based on projections and calculations, I'm not saying you have to wait until your server crashes. But I wouldn't denormalize because maybe possibly someday it will be a problem. This is especially true if there is any question whether you will really get a net gain. Why screw up your database for an optimization that isn't particularly needed and that may not even materialize?

Comment: Thanks, I'm also agree to your argument on this.

Answer (score 4):

There is no one single answer to the question of which design is going to give you better performance or, more generally, better results.  It depends strongly on how you use the data.  There are aspects of the data you need to look at in addition to the simple number of columns and number of rows.  Are all of the columns closely related to the primary key of the table?  If not, you may want to go through a careful process of normalization in order to decompose the table into several tables that conform to a higher normal form.

Are you familiar with the various normal forms, and with the consequences of departing from these normal forms?  Expert designers sometimes disregard normalization rules, but they know what they are doing, and they are aware of the downside of not normalizing.

Do the entities (objects) that are represented in the table all belong to the same type, or can that type be split into several subtypes (subclasses)?  If so,  it may make sense to decompose the tables into one table for each class.  See the following link:

http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html

Finally, and most importantly, you are probably pursuing more than one goal in your table design.  In addition to speed, there is flexibility and adaptability, ease of learning, ease of use and programming, and freedom from internal contradictions in the data.  You have to balance these goals in order to answer the question of how your tables should be composed.

Comment: We represent several type of data in the same table. Yes I'm familiar with the concept of normalization and normalization forms. The thing is the table is all ready designed and not it is in the Production as well. I will go through the link you have provided and try to get some ideas as well. Thanks for the answer...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, creating the new table only because 'there are many columns yet' isn't wise. Additional table will hurt performance at any read or write operation which requires this column together with some other columns.

If table have 200+ columns it may have sense to redesign it completely. Such tables often have several 'column groups'; for example it may be like 'if record_type = 1 we operate with columns A, B and C; if record_type = 2 we operate with columns A, D and E and so on'. If so, it may be better to make these groups as separate tables. General condition is: you often work with columns of one group and you seldom should join these groups together.